# Null object for Criterion interface

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Is there any way to create a Null Object of a Criterion interface? This way I won't have to return null and fill my code with tests for null to avoid NPEs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an empty conjunction:

```
Restrictions.conjunction()
```

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4772

> According to spec, an empty conjunction (AND) should always resolve to
>   true while an empty disjunction (OR) should always resolve to false.

By the way, if your method can return a null / empty criterion, you may consider using the Guava class `Optional<Criterion>`

Check also that: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5795